# Is there a function that reshapes all arrays so the broadcast has all arrays on different dims

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have 3 arrays with shape(3,) that you want to find the product them on different dimensions such that the result is an array of shape(3,3,3). I know that you can reshape them and then use broadcasting rules to find the product.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])

a.reshape(1,1,-1)*b.reshape(1,-1,1)*c.reshape(-1,1,1)
```

Is there a function or method to reshape the arrays to achieve same result?

My solution:

```
d = [a,b,c,a,b,c] # arrays = 6
l = len(d) # n arrays
```

I then create a n*n array with all ones but with the diagonal being negative to set the shape (-1,1,1,1,1,1),(1,-1,1,1,1,1) etc.

```
sh = (np.ones((l,l))-np.eye(l)*2).astype(int)
```

Zip the target array with the shape and then index the resulting list to find the product. In this case the output has shape (3,3,3,3,3,3).

```
z = [j.reshape(i) for i,j in zip(sh,d)]
z[0]*z[1]*z[2]*z[3]*z[4]*z[5]
```

Im certain there is a better way for this - can anyone help?

Comment: (1) What is wrong with the reshape method? (2) Tip: You can create the matrix of ones with negative ones on the diagonal as `sh = np.ones((l,l), dtype=np.int32); np.fill_diagonal(sh, -1)`.

Comment: @jared (1) Reshape method works but is annoying if you have more than 4 arrays, I'd like a more pythonic way.  (2) Nice.

Comment: I like `a[:,None,None]*b[:,None]+c`. Or `A,B,C=np.ix_(a,b,c)`.  `meshgrid` with `sparse=True` is useful. `np.ogrid` is another tool.

Comment: @hpaulj That's it! `.ix_` and `.meshgrid` are exactly the one line solutions that I knew had to exist...

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you are computing is

```py
np.einsum('i,j,k',a,b,c)
```

Or `np.einsum('a,b,c',a,b,c)`. That's the same. It is more common to start at i, and I didn't want to create confusion, and make believe that the subscript strings have something to do with variable names

If that is not automatic enough, you can

```py
def myProd(*v):
    return np.einsum(','.join("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[:len(v)]), *v)
```

And then

```py
myProd(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Whilst this works, I think the `np.ix_` makes more sense in my application since if you change the operation from product to something more complex it doesn't work - although I didnt stipulate this in the question.  E.g `a**b+c`.